# in PowerBI - How to group a table by a column, and return all unique values (coma seperated) from another column as grouped

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to group a table by a column, so the resulted table have unique values in that column, and also returns all the unique values from another column that belonged to the grouped column:

Source:

Country = USA

Cities =
New York
Boston
Chicago
Houston

Transform: group by [Country] column, and return unqiue values from [Cities] and coma seperated:

Country = USA
Cities = New York,Boston,Chicago,Houston

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use **`CONCATENATEX`** in a measure

[image: s1]

**`Measure = CONCATENATEX(VALUES('Table'[Cities]),'Table'[Cities],",")`**

Comment: lovely, thanks smpa01